# Combinatoric Vector Addition Minimization Problem

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, mathematical-optimization, job-scheduling

I'm working on a problem, and it feels like it might be analogous to an existing problem in mathematical programming, but I'm having trouble finding any such problem.

The problem goes like this: We have *n* sets of *d* dimensional vectors, such that each set contains exactly *d*+1 vectors. Within each set, all vectors have the same length (furthermore, the angle between any two vectors in a set is the same for any set, but I'm not sure whether this relevant). We then need to choose exactly one vector out of every set, and compute the sum of these vectors. Our objective is to make our choices so that the sum of the vectors is minimized.

It feels like the problem is sort of related to the Shortest Vector Problem, or a variant of job scheduling, where scheduling a job on a machine affects all machines, or a partition problem.

Does this problem ring a bell? Specifically, I'm looking for research into solving this problem, as currently my best bet is using an ILP, but I feel there must be something more clever that can be done.

Comment: What's the range and type of the entries in each vector?

Comment: The vectors consists of reals, with no limited range given. But if limiting the range or type of the entries allows for a solution I'm interested to know.

Comment: Are you sure that each set has d+1 vectors? I believe that you can only have d with the same pairwise angles.

Comment: I'm puzzled like @NicoSchertler: e.g., how can you have 4 vectors in 3 dimensions all at the same angle to each other?

Comment: furthermore: what do you mean by ILP?

Comment: last but not least: I guess that when you say that the sum must be minimized, you mean that the Euclidean norm of the resulting vector (the square root of the sum of the squares of the components) must be minimized, right?

Comment: @WalterTross Look at the vectors from the center of a tetrahedron through the center of its faces.  That gives you 4 vectors in 3 d, the angles between any two of which is exactly the same.  Also ILP likely means [Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) which is a standard approach for solving a variety of NP-complete problems in practice.

Comment: I see, @btilly, but then I don't understand why the OP treated this aspect as possibly irrelevant. An even simpler example would be in 2D, where 3 vectors would have to be at 180° from each other.

Comment: @WalterTross I did not state the norm because I'm not completely sure which norm is most relevant to my problem (this question is actually already a translation of my original problem, and I posed it this way as this seems like something that would already exist), and didn't want to limit the possible responses to a single norm.

Also, I excluded the angles as possibly irrelevant because they make the problem really specific. As mentioned, these vectors will always form a d-simplex, and I expected that that wouldn't pop up in research as easily as the more general case.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) or MISOCP (mixed integer second-order cone) problem:

Let

```
 v(i,j) be i vectors in group j (data)
 x(i,j) in {0,1}: binary decision variables
 w: sum of selected vectors (decision variable)
```

Then the problem can be stated as:

```
 min ||w||
 sum(i, x(i,j)) = 1   for all j
 w = sum((i,j), x(i,j)*v(i,j))
```

If you want you can substitute out `w`. Indeed I don't use your angle restriction (this is a restriction on the data and not on the decision variables of the model). The `x` variables are chosen such that we select exactly one vector from each group.

Minimizing the 2-norm can be replaced by minimizing the sum of the squares of the elements (i.e. minimizing the square of the norm).

Assuming the 2-norm, this is a MISOCP problem or convex MIQP problem for which quite a few solvers are available. For 1-norm and infinity-norms we can formulate a linear MIP problem. MIP solvers are widely available.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am unfamiliar with MISOCP, what would be the advantage of modelling the problem in this way compared to an MIQP problem?

Comment: In most cases QPs are translated automatically into SOCPs when appropriate. So at the modeling level you can just provide a (MI)QP. SOCP is more general class of problems, and QPs may be solved more efficiently as an SOCP than using more traditional QP methods. I just mentioned MISOCP in my answer to make sure that you include them as quite appropriate technology for your problem.